# Confused about number in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I was reading a SQL "cookbook" type reference, and I came across a statement that I has never come across before:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
SELECT t.col1, 8
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.col2 = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8
```

Now what confuses me is a number (in this example, 8) immediately following the SELECT statement. In my limited SQL experience, I have only come across SELECT queries that are followed by column names. Could somebody help me understand what this does? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SELECT 8, 8` does exactly what it appears to do; it returns a result set with 2 un-named columns each containing `8` - if you run just that statement yourself you'll see exactly that.

You are free to select literal values & expressions just as you are columns, function results etc;

```
SELECT 'cake', 123 + 456
```

The `UNION ALL` merges (non-duplicate) rows from the 1st table select with the result of the 2nd select so your inserting a single additional `(8,8)` row into the table.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'm sure this is a fairly common statement, but I just hadn't come across it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a literal value to the select statement.

In this case it will just add an additional column to the result with the value 8 for all rows.

You can also use functions that don't reference columns similarly. e.g.

```
SELECT t.col1, NOW() AS t
```

The `AS t` defines a column alias for the extra column. This is not important in your example as it is just used as the source for an `insert` anyway.

I won't bother addressing the `UNION ALL` as that isn't the point of confusion to you.

Answer (score 2):

It selects the literals 8 and 8.  The statement will insert into table the values of col1 and 8 from table where col2 of table = 5 AND one more row with values 8 and 8

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
```

Insert into a table named `table1` a row with values for `col` and `col2`.
Set all other columns to their default value (or null if there is none).

```
SELECT t.col1, 8
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.col2 = 5
```

Insert the output of this select statement.
Note that `select 8` will substitute a literal 8 in every row of the output.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8
```

Put an extra row with just col1=8, col2=8 in the result.

**Links**:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

From the last link:

> SELECT can also be used to retrieve rows computed without reference to any table.
>   For example:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 + 1;
       -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can SELECT anything you want, starting from table fields, ending at custom expressions that can be evaluated by SQL engine (for example table.field * 2). In this query you'll have 8 as fields of every returned record.

Answer (score 1):

It is the relational operation known as ['extend'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#The_extend_operation) (interestingly, Codd initially omitted extend from his relational algebra, probably because he envisaged calculations being done in the 'front end').

Although typically used for calculation, extension involving a literal is allowed and, while not terribly useful, from a language design point of view there is no reason to disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a value directly in a SELECT statement. t.col1 is actually a variable which will have different values in different returned registers. 8 is a literal value.